# Identifying transitions in an array

Tags: conditional, numeric-array

I have two arrays of elements. The second array is generated by the transfer of one or more element to another position. I want to know which element is transferred to which position. Following is the simple example

```
A1 = {a, a, a, a, a, a};
A2 = {2a, 0, 2a, 0, a, a};
```

In this example the o/p I am looking for is {2->1 and 4->3}. How to achieve this ?
Also, I want to have preference order in transitions. For example above example could also give {2->3, 4-> 1}. But I want to put conditions suggesting some transitions are less likely than others. So in above case, 2-> 3 is less probable than 2-> 1. so the o/p should be {2->1 and 4->3}.

Will be thankful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for the simple example in OP:

```
Rule @@@ Transpose[PositionIndex[A2] /@ {0, 2 a}]
```

> {2 -> 1, 4 -> 3}

A generalization for cases where `A1` is a constant array:

```
ClearAll[posMap]
posMap = Module[{pos1 = Flatten[Position[#, 0]], 
  pos2 = Flatten @ MapIndexed[ConstantArray[#2[[1]], #] &, 
     Ramp[Coefficient[#, Variables[#][[1]]] - 1]]},
 Thread[pos1 -> pos2]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
posMap[A2]
```

> {2 -> 1, 4 -> 3}

```
posMap[{3 a, 0, a, 0, a, a}]
```

> {2 -> 1, 4 -> 1}

```
posMap[{3 a, 0, 0, a, 0, 2 a, a}]
```

> {2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 5 -> 6}

Comment: Thanks. It works, but I how to make it more general. For example if A2 = {3a, 0, 0, a, a, a}. It should give {2-> 1, 3-> 1}

Comment: @user49535, please see the update.

Comment: Thanks, it is working. A confession - After spending more than two hours, I am still not able to understand how it is working. Specially the part                                  
 # /.{k_Integer x_ :> ConstantArray[#2[[1]], k - 1], _ -> Nothing}                                              It is very naive, but can you please tell what this step is doing ! I tried to run this part with a separate array but no clue what is going on.  I understand that k_Integer restricts the values of k to integers but what does "k_Integer x_" mean ? Could not find anything similar anywhere else also! Thanks

Comment: @user49535, `k_Integer x_` is a pattern that matches `2a`, `5 b`, `10 xxx` etc. The replacement rule works as follows: If, say,  `4a` appears in the 2nd position of input list,  it is replaced with `{2,2,2}` if it appears in the 5th position it is replaced with `{5,5,5}`;  and element that does not match the pattern is removed (this is the `_ -> Nothing` part).

Comment: Two points to understand 1. ConstantArray[#2[[1]], k-1] is generating an array of k-1 elements with each element being same as first element of A2, which is 2a

Comment: Two points I want your confirmation on 1. ConstantArray[#2[[1]], k-1] is generating an array of k-1 elements with each element being same as first element of A2, which is 2a. How k is acquiring numerical values here ?                                                 2. For A1 = {a, a, a, a, a, a} and A2={2a, 0, a, a, a, a}, is this step creating {{a, a}, 0, a, a, a, a} ?  Thanks

Comment: "an array of k-1 elements with each element being same as" **_the position of the element that matches `k_Integer x_`**_  (which is 1   or  3 for `A2`).

Comment: for `A2={2a, 0, a, a, a, a}`  replacement step (together with `_-> Nothing`) creates `{1}`; for `A2={3a, 0, a, 5a, a, a, 0,0,0,0}` this step creates `{1,1, 4,4,4,4}`.

Comment: Finally it worked for my problem, thanks for all your help